# Accessing state of Statefull Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a situtation where i would like to access to text of a text controller, from the Widget part of a statefull widget.

So what i would like to do is is write a method getText() that returns the current text in my _textController.

I know how to do this from the other way around. If i need to get data from my widget from the State part of my widget is use "widget.", but i dont know how to do this the other way around.

```dart
class MyTextWidget extends StatefulWidget {
 
  String getText() {
    // how can i access the _textController.text from here?
  }

  @override
  _MyTextWidgetState createState() => _MyTextWidgetState();
}

class _MyTextWidgetState extends State<MyTextWidget> {
  final TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();

  
  _MyTextWidgetState();


  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
        child: TextField(
          controller: _textController,
          key: ValueKey('MyTextWidgetinput_Key'),
          maxLines: null,
          autofocus: true,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0))),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move it up and access it in your state class using `widget._textController`:

```
class MyTextWidget extends StatefulWidget {
 
  final TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();

  String getText() {
    _textController.text // do something with it
    // how can i access the _textController.text from here?
  }

  @override
  _MyTextWidgetState createState() => _MyTextWidgetState();
}

class _MyTextWidgetState extends State<MyTextWidget> {
  

  _MyTextWidgetState();


  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget._textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
        child: TextField(
          controller: widget._textController,
          key: ValueKey('MyTextWidgetinput_Key'),
          maxLines: null,
          autofocus: true,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0))),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```